# how to make CDockablePane unfocusable?

Tags: c++, mfc

i create a CDockablePane as well as a CView in the main frame of my application. i need the pane not to get focused. this causes the active view to lose focus and doesn't receive keyboard events anymore. the pane consists of tool boxes. they're dragged into the view. but the pane and its children must not get focus ever.
how can it be achieved? i tried ModifyStyleEx after creation of the pane for setting WS_EX_NOACTIVATE. but it didn't change the pane's behavior. i also tried ModifyStyle to set WS_DISABLED. but it completely disables dragging tools from the pane.

Comment: And how should a user use your toolbox with the Keyboard, when it never gets the Focus. Nearly all controls move the Focus to a Control when a mouse click is performed. When you want that after an Action or selection in the Toolbox the active view should be active again, than use SetFocus and move the Focus back to the view when it is appropriate.

Comment: Have you tried to handle CDockablePane::OnActivate ? There, you can move when you want the focus anywhere ...  delayed or not ...

Comment: @xMRi: good question, but i want none of them to get focused, because they're just dragged with mouse and the user never expects them to get focus and receive keyboard events.
flaviu2: i'll try it. but even if this method works, flicker in the color of the pane title bar happens which i prefer to avoid. the pane must just be unfocusable, so that no child control in it as well as itself can get focus.